# Return true for rows that have positive value

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with emphasizing an advertisement -  need to have to different designs for enhanced and non-enhanced ad's!

My table is like this:

```
id   int(11) UNIQUE  // the unique id of the row
adresse   text   // the adress of an advertisement
fremhaevninger  int(11)   // the number of emphasizings of the ad
dato   datetime  // when the row was added
```

I need to have a script, that can return me e.g. a variable like

```
$enhanced = 1;

if 'fremhaevninger' > 0 - else

$enhanced = 0;
```

NOTE: 'fremhaevninger' can be anything from 0 to 99.999.999.999

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT
  otherfields,
  IF(fremhaevninger > 0, 1, 0) AS enhanced
FROM
  ....
```

Comment: Nice, thanks - didn't even knew something like that existed in SQL :) .. lol

Comment: Well I actually need something else...

In the WHERE-clause I need it to make sure, that the rows with fremhaevninger > 0 is returned BEFORE the rows with fremhaevninger = 0 :)

Comment: Yeesh. Picky, aren't you... `ORDER BY enhanced DESC`

Comment: I thought you could only use actually fields in the WHERE/ORDER BY-clause :) .. my bad - thanks !

Comment: Is it possible to write something like this:

ORDER BY
   enhanced rand(),
   id DESC

Comment: Commas between the fields, but `id` is likely to override any randomization.

Comment: Yes, but i want it to FIRST of all order by "enhanced" randomly... secondly order by id DESC if enhanced = 0 :)